# Is it possible to connect a MusicPlayer using MusicSequence to AVAudioUnitSampler?

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, audiokit

I'm using Audiokit for the audio needs of my iOS app, where I need to use a sequencer to programmatically control a sequence of notes and I want to drive a sampler with it. Audiokit seems to be designed to use MIDI internally, but I'd like to avoid this and go directly from sequencer to sampler, because using MIDI seems to make all the internal connections appear in virtual MIDI lists in other apps.

My question is this: Is it possible to connect a sequencer using `MusicPlayer`, `MusicSequence` and `MusicTrack` (from AudioToolbox) to an `AVAudioUnitSampler` (from AVFoundation)?

The other option would apparently be to construct the sampler using an `AudioComponentDescription` and building an `AUGraph`, but I'd like to use the Audiokit helpers as far as possible.

EDIT: The critical step seems to be using `MusicTrackSetDestNode` that takes an `AUNode`. `AVAudioUnitSampler` is an `AVAudioNode` that has the `auAudioUnit` property, of type `AUAudioUnit`. Essential APIs like `AUGraphNodeInfo` give you the audio unit from the audio node. How do you get the audio node from the audio unit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use AVAudioSequencer easily with AVAudioUnitSampler. This works for many cases.

It doesn't work for MIDI sequences that are built "on the fly" because there is no API to create sequences besides the AudioToolbox right now. File a Radar asking for this. (They're tired of hear from me about this). Otherwise, one clunky way is to create a MusicSequence, convert that to a Data instance, then hand that to AVAudioSequencer.

Comment: Yes I've read your posts, unfortunately it's about the only thing that really turns up. I really only asked because a) I'd like to use Audiokit and take the shortcuts it provides and b) I specifically need to build the sequence on the fly. I guess it's time to accept that there is no better answer here despite this and accept your answer to inform others. Next step, learn to file a radar...

Comment: I too would love to see a viable way to populate an `AVAudioSequencer` with MIDI data on the fly. Thanks mostly to your posts, Gene, I have a pretty viable player, but if it can't take MIDI information that's not pre-loaded on a file, I'm a bit stuck!

Comment: I am also trying to build a MIDI sequence "on the fly". Do any of you know if there have  been any updates to AVAudioSequencer to allow this?